# st_asmvt getting error in Greenplum with postgis extension

Tags: greenplum

I have succefully install the greenplum and postgis extension. when I use the PostGIS function st_asmvtgeom,I am getting the following error:
ERROR: Missing libprotobuf-c (lwgeom_out_mvt.c:46)(seg0 slice1 ip:6001 pid=72306)(lwgeom_out_mvt.c:46)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for this on the interweb yields a very clear answer to your problem: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271116/st-asmvt-error-missing-libprotobuf-c
Please do some research before asking questions here.